# Google Maps JS API disable transit information

Tags: google-maps

I have a typescript Angular 14 library that uses the Google Maps JS API.
In this app, I would like to disable the transit details information (all the white balloons on the green path).
Is there a way?

[image]

Here the code starting from line 24 of the example below

```
  directionsService
    .route({
      origin: { lat: 37.77, lng: -122.447 },
      destination: { lat: 37.768, lng: -122.511 },
      // Note that Javascript allows us to access the constant
      // using square brackets and a string value as its
      // "property."
      travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode[selectedMode],
    })
    .then((response) => {
      directionsRenderer.setDirections(response);
    })
    .catch((e) => window.alert("Directions request failed due to " + status));
```

Here an example from Google
https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/googlemaps/js-samples/tree/master/dist/samples/directions-travel-modes/jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly modify the `DirectionsRenderer`, so you would have to render your own custom polyline.

You can manually render the transit directions by getting the `overview_path` from the `DirectionsResult` object and create a `Polyline` object to visually represent the actual path of the route from point A to point B.

```js
function initMap() {
  const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    zoom: 13,
    center: {
      lat: 37.77,
      lng: -122.490
    },

  });


  const directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

  const origin = {
    lat: 37.77,
    lng: -122.447
  };
  const destination = {
    lat: 37.768,
    lng: -122.511
  };

  const request = {
    origin: origin,
    destination: destination,
    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.TRANSIT
  };
  //console.log(request)

  directionsService.route(request, function(result, status) {
    if (status === google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      
      const route = result.routes[0];
      console.log(route)
      
      // Get the overview_path from the routes result
      const path = route.overview_path

      // Create polyline to visually display the route from point A to B
      const pathPolyline = new google.maps.Polyline({
        path: path,
        geodesic: true,
        strokeColor: "#FF0000",
        strokeOpacity: 1.0,
        strokeWeight: 2,
      });


      //Adding marker for origin and destination

      const originMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: origin,
        map: map,
        title: 'Origin'
      })

      const destinationMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: destination,
        map: map,
        title: 'Destination'
      })

      pathPolyline.setMap(map);
    }
  });
}
window.initMap = initMap;
```

```css
#map {
  height: 100%;
}

/* 
 * Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. 
 */
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<!--
 @license
 Copyright 2019 Google LLC. All Rights Reserved.
 SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0
-->
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Travel Modes in Directions</title>
    <script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=default"></script>
    <!-- jsFiddle will insert css and js -->
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>

    <!-- 
      The `defer` attribute causes the callback to execute after the full HTML
      document has been parsed. For non-blocking uses, avoiding race conditions,
      and consistent behavior across browsers, consider loading using Promises.
      See https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/load-maps-js-api
      for more information.
      -->
    <script
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initMap&v=weekly"
      defer
    ></script>
  </body>
</html>
```